# Splitting, re-encoding and joining video files results in clicking audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, encoding, video-encoding

We want to encode large video files faster.
To make encoding faster we are using multiple encoding servers.
Below is our process of encoding flow

1. First we split the video into small segments using below command

   `ffmpeg -i F:\video_data_set\4k_compressed.mp4 -f segment -segment_time 5 -segment_start_number 1 -codec copy -copyts -avoid_negative_ts 1 F:\video_data_set\test\%d_4k_compressed.mp4`
2. Then we divide these segments among multiple encoding servers
   Each encoding server re-encode the segment using below command

   `ffmpeg -hide_banner -i F:\video_data_set\test\1_4k_compressed.mp4 -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -x264opts nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -vf "scale=1280:-2,setdar=16:9" -b:v 3.9M -minrate 3.9M -maxrate 3.9M -bufsize 7.8M -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -r 30 -g 30 -threads 8 F:\video_data_set\test\1_4k_compressed_1.mp4`
3. When all segments have re-encoded then we join them to make single file using below command

   `ffmpeg -hide_banner -f concat -safe 0 -i F:\video_data_set\test\files_2.txt -c copy -threads 8 F:\video_data_set\4k_compressed_1.mp4`

All is performing well but the issue we are facing is that after each segment there is click sound in output audio.

For example I have encoded 5 segments having duration 6,6,3,6 and 6 seconds when I joined them using above mentioned command the output video has click sound at 6,12,15 and 21 seconds of video.

Can you please help me and let me know what is the cause of this click sound and how to fix and remove this click sound from output video.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known effect: The `-segment` splits the video on a valid video entry point (i.e. an I-frame) but not always on a valid audio entry point.

The best way to work around this is to split the video and the audio in the first step:

```
ffmpeg -i F:\video_data_set\4k_compressed.mp4 -f segment -segment_time 5 -segment_start_number 1 -c:v copy -an -copyts -avoid_negative_ts 1 F:\video_data_set\test\%d_4k_compressed.mp4 -vn -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 128k F:\video_data_set\test\audio.m4a
```

then proceed with the video segments as in your current workflow.

For the final step use

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -f concat -safe 0 -i F:\video_data_set\test\files_2.txt -i F:\video_data_set\test\audio.m4a -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -threads 8 F:\video_data_set\4k_compressed_1.mp4
```

To re-add the audio.

Comment: Hello Eugen i have tested that solution but in this way audio out of sync i think some frames dropped in this way due to which audio is out of sync please help me to solve that problem

Comment: Have you tried the SETPTS and ASETPTS filters to nail the audio sync?

Comment: No i have not tried these filters how i can use these filters

Comment: Read up in the documentation - the point ist to set the PTS for Video and Audio to the same value when splitting, as they might have an offset that doesn't show when interleaved.

Comment: Hello Eugen can you please let me know to which splitting value we need to set audio and video pts i have read the documentation audio video pts have constant values

Comment: I'd start with `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS` and `asetpts=N/SR/TB`, but `setpts=N/(25*TB)`(for 25fps) might be an idea as well.